# perl - Math with duplicate entries in array

Tags: perl

I have two arrays:

```
my @name = (bob, bob, dave, john, john, mary, mary, mary);
my @cost = (5, 7, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3 , 4);
```

I want to map them together so the output would just be:

```
bob 12
dave 4
john 8
mary 13
```

The array's change though so I can't use references. How do I group `@cost` by `@name` and add the values of `@cost`?

Comment: Do you want to create a new array with the result or just print the results?

Comment: Use a hash, adding the value of `@cost` to the value of the key from `@name`.

Comment: Anyway is fine. I'd like to have the printed output be `'bob'=12 'dave'=4` etc. Right now I'm just stuck on the math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper;
my @name = qw(bob bob dave john john mary mary mary);
my @cost = qw(5 7 4 4 4 6 3 4);
my %seen = ();
foreach(0..scalar(@name)-1){
    if (!exists $seen{$name[$_]}){
        $seen{$name[$_]} = $cost[$_];
    }
    else{
        my $sum = 0;
        $sum = $seen{$name[$_]};
        my $new = $sum + $cost[$_];
        $seen{$name[$_]} = $new;
    }
}
print Dumper(\%seen);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$VAR1 = {
    'bob' => 12,
    'john' => 8,
    'dave' => 4,
    'mary' => 13
};
```

Comment: FWIW:  I'd probably iterate to `$#name` instead of `scalar(@name)-1`.  Also, taking advantage of autovivification allows you to forgo the `if` clause and just run with what's contained in your `else` block.

Comment: @tjd Indeed, that would be better but I prefer using these simple lines sometimes It becomes difficult to understand some features.

Comment: I always feel uncomfortable when I see `if (! ...) { ... } else { ... }`. Surely that's better written with the if/else clauses the other way round and the `!` removed from the condition. But as tjd points out, autovivification means that you don't need that check at all. Also, you're unnecessarily quoting your hash key (`"$name[$_]"`) in some places, but not in others. That's going to confuse people.

Comment: Edited the answer, Removed the quoted hash key and I didn't use **autovivification** because for some people that's also difficult to understand.

Comment: But you left the weirdly inverted if/else logic.

Answer (score 6):

A more perlish bit of code that will consume the input:

```
my %Cost_by_Name;
while (@name & @cost) {
    $Cost_by_Name{shift @name} += shift @cost;
}
```

..because that source data doesn't deserve to live.

Comment: @AbhiNickz just realize that it can be dangerous to modify data structures as you're iterating over them.

Answer (score 4):

Some [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) trickery:

```
my %hash;
%hash = map {$name[$_] => $hash{$name[$_]} += $cost[$_]} 0..$#name;
```

Personally, I'd go with a `for()` or `while()` loop solution though, as it's much easier to see what's happening at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
my %myHash = ();
for (my $i=0 ; $i<$#name ; $i++) {
    $myHash{$name[$i]} += $cost[$i];
}
```

Then you just have to loop through the array to get the total cost:

```
for (keys %myHash) {...}
```

Comment: You can usually replace a C-style `for` loop like yours with a (in my opinion) easier to understand `foreach` loop. in this case, it would be `foreach my $i (0 .. $#name)`

Comment: @DaveCross True. But for SO answers I tend to prefer classic "for", as they are a bit more universal/language-agnostic. For my own code, however, anything goes :)

Comment: For SO answers I prefer whatever construct makes the code easier to read. And that's rarely the C-style loop. I find it far too easy to make off-by-one errors when using it.