# Perl auto-vivification on assignment

Tags: perl, autovivification

Does Perl real auto-vivifies key when the unexisting key is assigned to a variable?

I have this code :

`my $variable = $self->{database}->{'my_key'}[0];`

The variable `$self->{database}->{'my_key'}[0]` is undefined in my hash, but if I print a Dumper after the assignment, I'm surprised that the `my_key` is created.

I know the functionality for this case :

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $array;

$array->[3] = 'Buster';  # autovivification
print Dumper( $array );
```

This will give me the results :

`$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          'Buster'
        ];`

But never expected to work the other way arround, where : 
`my $weird_autovivification = $array->[3];` 
will also vivify `$array->[3]`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Borodin updated, my bad. Is this really Perl's behavior?

Comment: Yes, It creates the key with the autovivification feature.

Comment: @AbhiNickz even on checking? E.g. `if ( defined $self->{'unexisting_key'})` .. 'cuz that would be sad..

Comment: No, You can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376841/perl-math-with-duplicate-entries-in-array/42377203#42377203) to get the idea about autovivification.

Comment: @AbhiNickz, Huh, no autovivification happens in the code in that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376841/perl-math-with-duplicate-entries-in-array/42377203#42377203). Did you link to the wrong answer?

Comment: @John Doe, Re "*even on checking*", Only on deferencing. That snippet dereferences `$self`, so `$self` we be autovivified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Does Perl real auto-vivifies key when the unexisting key is assigned to a variable?*

Perl autovivifies *variables* (including array elements and hash values) when they are *dereferenced*.

```
$foo->{bar}   [ $foo dereferenced as a hash   ]    ≡    ( $foo //= {} )->{bar}
$foo->[3]     [ $foo dereferenced as an array ]    ≡    ( $foo //= [] )->[3]
$$foo         [ $foo dereferenced as a scalar ]    ≡    ${ $foo //= do { my \$anon } }
etc
```

This means that

```
$self->{database}->{'my_key'}[0]
```

autovivifies

- `$self` (to a hash ref if undefined)
- `$self->{database}` (to a hash ref if undefined)
- `$self->{database}->{'my_key'}` (to an array ref if undefined)

but not

- `$self->{database}->{'my_key'}[0]` (since it wasn't dereferenced)

---

> *But never expected to work the other way arround, where : `my $weird_autovivification = $array->[3];` will also vivify `$array->[3]`.*

Not quite. It autovivifies `$array`, the variable being dereferenced. Nothing was assigned to `$array->[3]` since it wasn't dereferenced.

---

Tip: The [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) pragma can be used to control when autovivification occurs.

Answer (score 11):

> But never expected to work the other way arround, where :  `my
>   $weird_autovivification = $array->[3];` will also vivificate `$array[3]`.

That's not how it works.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'$foo=$array->[3]; say Dumper $array'
$VAR1 = [];
```

Executing that code has turned `$array` into an array reference (where, previously, it would have been undefined), but it hasn't set `$array->[3]` to anything.

If we add another level of look-up, we get slightly different behaviour:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'$foo=$array->[0][3]; say Dumper $array'
$VAR1 = [
          []
        ];
```

Here, Perl has created `$array->[0]` and set it to a reference to an empty array, but it hasn't affected `$array->[0][3]`.

In general, as you're going through a chain of look-ups in a complex data structure, Perl will autovivify all but the last link in the chain. When you think about it, that makes a lot of sense. Perl needs to autovivify one link in the chain so that it can check the existence of the next one.